# Calling swift UIView subclass function from objective C doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm trying to call a UIView subclass method from my objective C file but it doesn't work and throws the following error;

`No known class method for selector`

I'm having my swift UIView subclass like this;

```
 @objcMembers class FSBarGraph: UIView {
     @objc public func test() {...}
 }
```

And calling it like this;

```
[FSBarGraph test];
```

All my vars are already accessible so my `#import "FITsociety-Swift.h"` is working just fine. Also when I turn the method into a static or class one it can be found in objective-c, but I need it to be public.

How is this possible and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have to call it on an instance of your class, for example:

```
FSBarGraph *myGraphBar = [FSBarGraph new];
[myGraphBar test];
```

Comment: Ah, completely forgot that. It's so common to do that in Swift that I hadn't thought about it.

Answer (score 0):

test() is not a `class method` right now.

Try this:

```
@objcMembers class FSBarGraph: UIView {
     public static func test() {...}
 }
```